# Need help on Installed packages and permission sets

Tags: administration

The latest big thing happening is that there is an application which has been installed in the Sandbox called "PSA FinancialForce".

How can I see this installed application?
And I have couple of tasks on this using **permission sets**...

1. Should give "Full access to PSA with privileges for project creation and management,  resource creation, assignments, time-card entry".
2. Should give "Access to edit Project Tasks, View Projects, Self-assign, and enter time-cards".

Comment: One for @AndrewFawcett I would've thought ;)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You Can find the installed packages as shown in diagram above.

You can find documentation on permission sets here

https://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/perm_sets_create.htm

Also here is where you should begin and get started

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Installed apps show up exactly where @Mohith showed but the installed components will also show up under their individual setup nodes. So if you want to inspect any details (and some details are obfuscated in a managed package like Financial Force), you can navigate to each setup node and check it out.

There's a good chance that @AndrewFawcett included permission sets already in his package, but if not, you can create new ones. Keep in mind, when you installed the package, you were prompted to select security settings and depending on what you selected, you may already have the desired access added to your profiles.